# MySQL full text search on extracted json column

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am looking for answers to a particular scenario I am dealing with using MySQL's full text search and json column features.

I am storing unstructured/schema-less data in a json column that I want to enable full text search on. I am sure everybody knows MySQL does not allow FTS on json column. But there are ways around it and I have kind of settled on one but I am not sure what the implications of it will be in the long run.

Many people suggest copying the data that needs searching to a generated column. I cannot do that because, as I said, my data does not have any schema and it is not practical for me to create generated columns for all possibilities, it will defeat the purpose of using json in the first place.

So i thought about using just one generated column that takes the whole data from the source json column and stores it as json literal using MySQL's json_extract(). This appears to be working fine and I am satisfied with the results. I, however, am not sure about one thing. Storing json literal will mean storing other redundant things besides the actual data e.g. property keys/names. Considering how full text search works (inverted index and all), would redundant information like that have any effect on searching when data starts to grow? lets not worry about users trying to search for data using the json keys but instead on whether the inclusion if these keys from every row will affect FTS performance or not?

Last thing, yes I have done my homework, i know there are other better ways to do full text search but i am taking this path because of my situation and i need a really solid justification to look into alternate solutions.

Comment: *"I, however, am not sure about one thing. Storing json literal will mean storing other redundant things besides the actual data i.e. keys (ignoring other characters)"* Yes that can happen the parser keeps in mind [Stopwords](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-stopwords.html) and also considers [Minimum and Maximum Word Length](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-word-length)

Comment: Also there is a option of programming you own fulltext parser plugin see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/writing-full-text-plugins.html) to better handle JSON data..